# Does receiving a student visa replace my existing business travel visa? (China)

Tags: visas, china, business-travel, student-visas

Does receiving a student visa replace my existing business travel visa? Is it possible to hold two visa types simultaneously?

I still hold a now rare 10 year multiple entry "M" business travel visa (though COVID-19 rules mean this is temporarily unusable). If I receive a new visa e.g. student visa, must this replace my existing visa? or put another way, what would I expect to see when I receive my passport back from the embassy?

Comment: I assume your business visa is class M?

Comment: Yes, updated for clarification.